# How to get active window in e4 rcp application?

Tags: rcp, e4

I am currently working on a  project where I would like to  have  access to active Mwindow. In Eclipse 3.x through active workbench it was possible. But how can I achieve the same in eclipse 4 or e4? Any hints on  this will be appreciated.

Comment: do u want the window that represents the main window of the ui or do u want the window which is currently selected by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can just inject it.

For example in a handler you might do:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(MWindow window)
```

You can also use the `EModelService` to find windows with a particular id.

I would say that generally I don't find much need for the actual `MWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question actually, and just found a solution that couldn't be easier:

```
((MApplication) application).getSelectedElement();
```

The children of the MApplication singleton are MWindow elements solely, but I was not sure of how to find the active one in this list. Checked this line in a global handler routine and it really always returns the most active window, no matter if windows are changed via task bar, clicking on headers or specific parts.

Well done, Eclipse team! It's just not that easy to find all these neat little tricks you've built in, as always!

Answer (score -1):

For the eclipse4 ui the following works for me:

```
  MApplication application = E4Workbench.getServiceContext().get(MApplication.class);
```

This line calls the root of the ui model. It contains every window and their children. With...

```
MTrimmedWindow mWindow = (MTrimmedWindow) application.getChildren().get(0);
```

you will recieve the main window of the ui.

Hope it helps. If not - feel free to give me a hint what you need instead :)

Comment: `E4Workbench` is an **internal** class,  you should not be using it.

Answer (score -1):

I am using this bunch of code to get active Mwindow in E4

```
    IEclipseContext serviceContext = E4Workbench.getServiceContext();
    final IEclipseContext appContext = (IEclipseContext) serviceContext.getActiveChild();
    EModelService modelService = appContext.get(EModelService.class);
    MApplication application = serviceContext.get(MApplication.class);
    MWindow mWindow = application.getChildren().get(0);
```